# Query Help - How to get all customers who have shopped at any of the top 20 stores?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I need to get all customers who have shopped at ANY of the top 20 stores in terms of total sales ($). I would also like to have distinct customers.

These are the 5 tables I have.

Consumer : has customer id and some other details

merchant : has storeid (I didn't use this one)

transaction: has customer id and orderid, this table does not have item data.

order : has orderid and itemid and storeid

itemtable : has item details such as price, name and the orderid

So far I've got this query which doesn't seem to work.

```
select con.* 
from consumer con 
where con.id =
    (select 
        trans.consumerid 
    from transaction trans 
    join order ord on trans.orderid = ord.id 
    join
        (select 
            ord.merchantid 
        from order ord 
        join itemtable item on ord.id = item.orderid 
        group by ord.merchantid 
        order by sum(ordet.price) desc
        limit 50
        ) s20 
        on s20.merchantid = ord.merchantid
    )
```

It gives me this current error on Spark:

> Error in SQL statement: RuntimeException: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression:

I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Try to use in instead =. ` where con.id in (...)`

Comment: Since your subquery can return more than one value, you need to use `con.id IN (SELECT ...)` instead of `con.id = (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Let's pretend it's the top 3 stores. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ...and note that order is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`:

```
select c.* 
from consumer c 
where c.id in (select t.consumerid 
               from transaction t join 
                    order o
                    on t.orderid = o.id join
                    (select o.merchantid 
                     from order o join
                          itemtable i
                          on o.id = i.orderid 
                     group by o.merchantid 
                     order by sum(i.price) desc
                     limit 20
                    ) s20 
                    on s20.merchantid = o.merchantid
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

That thing you're trying to do with = should be done with join (or in, or exists)

```
select distinct con.* 
from
  consumer con    
  inner join transaction trans on con.id = trans.consumerid
  inner join order ord on trans.orderid = ord.id 
  inner join
    (select 
        ord.merchantid 
    from 
      `order` ord 
      inner join itemtable item on ord.id = item.orderid /*whaaat, a stock item has an orderid? Sounds messed up..*/
    group by ord.merchantid 
    order by sum(item.price) desc /*check this-your query has alias "ordet" not defined anywhere*/
    limit 20 /*you wrote 50?*/
    ) s20 
    on s20.merchantid = ord.merchantid
```